# Satis downloads nothing from packagist.org

Tags: php, satis

I've a problem with the Satis configuration. I've the following satis.json:

```
{
    "name": "Composer Test Repository",
    "homepage": "https://example.com",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "*"
    },
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist",
        "format": "zip",
        "skip-dev": true
    },
    "require-dependencies": true,
    "require-dev-dependencies": true,
    "providers": true
}
```

Then I start the build process by executing:

```
php satis.phar build -- satis.json /mypath
```

But the zend-mvc library is not downloaded and there will be no errors displayed.